# Deleting excess variables from stack - C++

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a recursive function that declares at least 50KB of local variables in one call and a stack overflow might be likely with the number of recursive steps I'll need. However, by the time the function is called within itself, these variables aren't needed anymore. Can I delete them, before the function call, to prevent them from consuming excess stack memory? I want to avoid using memory from the heap.

Comment: sounds like you don't need recursion ... why not make it iterative instead ?

Comment: I'm not sure so it's not an answer, but would enclosing them (and their use) in curly brackets do it, so that they're disposed of before the recursive call?

Comment: If you *must* make it recursive, try to make it tail-recursive and the compiler might be able to optimize it.

Comment: That's posh @JoachimPileborg.

Comment: if your function is tail-recursive, then there might not be a need to delete stuff from the stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* use recursion, then put those recyclable variables inside a `struct`, and pass that reusable `struct` instance (instantiated at the outermost layer of recursion) by reference to your recursive calls.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible solutions, the most plausible is to, in some way, remove that block of variables from the stack, either by passing it in from a lower level (and thus reusing the same space), or using dynamic allocation of some kind.

Or split the functions, such that the 50kb allocation is returned before you make the recursive call, something like this:

```
int do_stuff_on_stack()
{
   large variable;
   ... 
}


int recursive_call()
{
   int x = do_stuff_on_stack();

   if (something)
       int y = recursive_call();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int function(int c) {
    ...

    // Use anonymous parentheses to scope stack variables
    {
        int a = ...;
        int b = ...;
        c = ...;
    }
    ...

    return function(c);
}
```

Comment: @Mats Peterson why won't it?

Comment: Because compilers typically don't make multiple stack allocations in one function - it is a waste of effort, since allocating space on stack is done in a single instruction otherwise, and it makes the access to local variables within each scope complex. The constructors and destructors are called within the scope defined, but the space is gathered made up at entry and exit. Try looking at the code generated by the compiler if you don't believe me... [I have worked with gcc, clang, MSVC, High-C, CAD-UL C, Turbo C and armcc, and I have never seen stack deallocation in the middle of a function]

Comment: Yes. The example I've posted is actually too simple to explore the effects. So should be regarded as the principle only. I just compiled a simple function just now with (using "gcc -S # version 4.8.2") with and without the parentheses and noticed that there was no difference - this is compiler specific and dependent on what types your local variables are. The only way you'll find out if this helps is to try and see. One thing you can do is use multiple sets of parentheses within the body - there may be a chance the compiler reuses the same memory between each set.